# Defining a function with args to be used in df.transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy

For a current project, I am planning to winsorize a Pandas DataFrame that consists of two columns/objects `df['Policies']` and `df['ProCon']`. This means that the outliers at the high and the low end of the set shall be cut out.

The winsorising shall be conducted at `0.05` and `0.95` based on the values shown in the `df['ProCon']` section, while both columns shall be cut out in case an outlier is identified.

The code below is however not accepting the direct reference to the 'ProCon' column in line `def winsorize_series(df['ProCon']):`, yielding an error about an invalid syntax.

Is there any smart way to indicate that `ProCon` shall be the determining value for the winsorizing?

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mstats

# Loading the file
df = pd.read_csv("3d201602.csv")

# Winsorizing
def winsorize_series(df['ProCon']):
    return mstats.winsorize(df['ProCon'], limits=[0.05,0.95])

# Defining the winsorized DataFrame
df = df.transform(winsorize_series)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried separating the column name from the table?

```
def winsorize_series(df, column):
    return mstats.winsorize(df[column], limits=[0.05,0.95])
```

Can't test it though if there's no sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have tried this approach but am receiving the following error `TypeError: winsorize_series() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'`

Comment: @M.S., after calling a function like: `winsorize_series(df, 'ProCon')`?

Comment: `winsorize_series(df, 'ProCon'` was yielding an invalid syntax error, so I wrote it together again with the separate handling of df and column in the subsequent line

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, `.transform` is not the right choice to modify only one or selected columns from df. Whatever the function definition and arguments passed, transform will iterate and pass EVERY column to func and try to broadcast the joined result to the original shape of df.

What you need is much simpler

```
limits = [0.05,0.95] # keep limits static for any calls you make
colname = 'ProCon' # you could even have a list of columns and loop... for colname in cols

df[colname] = mstats.winsorize(df[colname], limits=limits)
```

---

`df.transform(func)` can be passed `*args` and `**kwargs` which will be passed to `func`, as in

```
df = df.transform(mstats.winsorize, axis=0, a=df['ProCon'], limits=[0.05,0.95])
```

So there is no need for

```
def winsorize_series...
```

Comment: That's a good thought. It however leads to `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` as message

Comment: No worries and thanks for your engagement - I think we are getting there. `TypeError: winsorize() got multiple values for argument 'a'` is the feedback I am receiving now. I saw that this happens when a keyword argument is specified that overwrites a positional argument...

Comment: Yes, we are trying to winsorize that series and each column of df at the same time, why use transform? Why not just `procon_winsorized = mstats.winsorize(df['ProCon'], limits=[0.05,0.95])`, in main and no need for functions

Comment: I just tried it - the code is leading to a table full of zeros. Anyways let me check if I may find a solution here.

Comment: It looks like you only need to winsorize that column, correct?

Comment: At the moment yes - I would ideally like the flexibility to determine what columns to winsorize, hence the point regarding the column definition